# Why can't linq find an implementation for mongodb?

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, asqueryable

I am trying to use linq in C# with mongodb per the tutorial here http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/

I have:

1. A using directive for MongoDB.Driver.Linq
2. A class with a few fields, inheriting another class which just provides the standard ObjectId Id field.
3. A reference to a collection of said class of type MongoCollection obtained Connection.GetCollection
4. Lastly, my query - from item in MyCollection.AsQueryable() select item;

The compiler complains that Error: Could not find an implementation of the query pattern...

What is missing?

---EDIT---

I have minimized the code here to illustrate the problem -

```
// .Net
using System.Collections.Generic;

// 3rd Party
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Builders;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;

namespace Chess2.Server {
    public static partial class Database {
        internal static MongoCollection<Document> Collection =
            GetCollection<Document>();
    }
    public class Document {
        public ObjectId Id;
        public int Field;

        public static IEnumerable<Document> Waiting() {
            // HERE IS THE LINQ THAT DOESN"T WORK
            return from item in
                       Database.Collection.AsQueryable<Document>()
                   where item.Field > 0
                   select item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the actual code rather than text describing it?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the suggestion I have done as you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for a Linq provider to be found, one must not only have the using statement for the provider, but also System.Linq itself.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing queryable type, at least that's what I think after looking at the tutorial link. If it is querying against `MongoCollection`, I think your query should've been :

```
var query = from item in MyCollection.AsQueryable<MongoCollection>() select item;
```

Comment: The documentation I linked to suggests that the document type be the generic parameter, not the collection. I have tried both per your suggestion and neither compile. Please see the recently added code sample above for more info.

Comment: with that code, are you still getting the same error message "*Could not find an implementation of the query pattern...*" ? or different error message now?

Comment: Same error. Here is the entire error - "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Chess2.Server.Document>'. 'Where' not found. Are you missing a reference or using directive for 'System.Linq'?

Comment: Hmm... here's a question. I may misunderstand how Linq providers work. If I add a reference to System.Linq, will it use the default linq implementation (bad) or is a reference to System.Linq compulsory for getting C# to use MongoDB.Driver.Linq? (Note: Adding the reference to System.Linq causes it to compile, but as I understand it if the default Linq implementation is used on the database it will lead to severe performance problems)

Comment: I'm not experienced with mongodb, but I think it is the latter. Native `Linq` won't be able to automatically deal with any kind of database (MongoDB in this case). If `System.Linq` works, it must be using MongoDB driver somehow.

Comment: Yes. Missing either using directive fails to compile. If you put this information into a different answer I will accept it to your credit.